# How can I enable iwd debug mode?

Tags: iwd

When I try to run any of the commands under `Station Debug`,

```
Station Debug:
  debug <wlan> connect <bssid>                        Connect to a specific BSS       
  debug <wlan> roam <bssid>                           Roam to a BSS                   
  debug <wlan> get-networks                           Get networks                    
  debug <wlan> autoconnect on|off                     Set AutoConnect property
```

I get *"IWD not in developer mode"*

```
[iwd]# debug wlan0 connect B4:75:0E:66:D9:C0
IWD not in developer mode
```

How can I put IWD in "developer mode"?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it from here, with the `--developer` flag:

```
sudo /usr/lib/iwd/iwdl -E
```

From the same path with `--help`:

```
iwd - Wireless daemon
Usage:
    iwd [options]
Options:
    -E, --developer        Enable developer mode
    -i, --interfaces       Interfaces to manage
    -I, --nointerfaces     Interfaces to ignore
    -p, --phys             Phys to manage
    -P, --nophys           Phys to ignore
    -d, --debug            Enable debug output
    -v, --version          Show version
    -h, --help             Show help options
```

Note that I have not actually tested this, as my IWD is totally broken right now and I have pretty much just given up on it